# Typescript: How to auto generate a d.ts file for image

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I'm working on a React application and using typescript & webpack, I know in typescript if you want import a image file you need to create a d.ts file in current directory and write this

```
// index.d.ts
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

my project directory structure like this

```
-- container
  -- Header
    -- Navigator
         avatar.png
         index.tsx
    -- Banner
         headerGround.png
         index.tsx
```

if I want to import png, I need to every directory write a d.ts file, it's too tedious for me, have any way to resolve it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Include your TypeScript Declaration File in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions" { ... },
    "include": ["path/to/index.d.ts"]
}
```

You can also use glob patterns. For example, you might have several declaration files in a `typings` directory.

```
"include": ["typings/*.d.ts"]
```

Read more about the tsconfig.json here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html